# Android updateAppWidget doesn't update

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I got a serious issue on my `Android application`:

Calling

```
AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, getWidgetView(context, appWidgetId));
```

in the `public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)` method has no result at all.
The `RemoteViews` that are produced looks to be valid (programatically speaking) but the `widget` is not updated (It keeps old values).

I've found some similar questions, but nobody has answer it:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18534990/updateappwidget-does-not-update-on-sony-xperia
- [AppWidget does not reliably update upon call updateAppWidget()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19248744/appwidget-does-not-reliably-update-upon-call-updateappwidget?rq=1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution posted by @Manitoba is not fully working, here is the working code to put inside `onUpdate` :

```
RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
// do your stuff
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, CustomWidgetProvider.class), views);
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 6):

Solved:

The solution was quite weird but using

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, CustomWidgetProvider.class), getWidgetView(context, appWidgetId));
```

solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

Tried all `updateAppWidget()` overloads, but it just doesn't work - whether called from `onReceive()` or `Activity`.
Strangely, `notifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged()` does work in the same scenario.

EDIT:

Android/Launcher must be caching `RemoteViews`, and if you call `updateAppWidget()` with exactly same `RemoteViews` - no rebind happens, despite what docs say, I can clearly see that my `RemoteViewsFactory` is not called. 
Because I needed to force UI rebind, ended up calling `updateAppWidget()` with some dummy layout, and immediately after that with normal layout again:

```
            try { 
                mgr.updateAppWidget(widgetId, new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.dummy)); 
            } finally { 
                mgr.updateAppWidget(widgetId, GetRemoteView(context, widgetId)); 
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

What I've found for updating widget for xPeria is to add after
        .putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

This line :

```
<intent>.setData(Uri.withAppendedPath(
        Uri.parse("imgwidget://widget/id/"),
        String.valueOf(allWidgetIds)));
```

Where is

```
Intent active = new Intent(context, <widget_provider>.class);
```